# Setting chmod on all .htaccess files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, chmod

How can I find and set chmod 444 to all .htaccess files in a directory (for security purposes)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have access to SSH, you could do this:

```
find . -name .htaccess | xargs chmod 444
```

Which would recursively do a `chmod` on all the `.htaccess` files found from the current directory you ran the command at.

If you want to specify a folder you could do it like this:

```
find /home/your_account/public_html -name .htaccess | xargs chmod 444
```

## **NOTE**

MAKE SURE TO PROPERLY ADD DOUBLE QUOTES IF YOUR PATH HAVE SPACES TO AVOID THE ABOVE COMMAND FROM APPLYING THE CHMOD WRONGLY.

Example:

```
find /home/my account/public_html/
```

Use double quotes:

```
find "/home/my account/public_html/" -name .htaccess | xargs chmod 444
```

---

You can also list the files prior using the command to make sure it is working to your needs like this:

```
find . -name .htaccess -print
```

Or with a folder path:

```
find /home/your_account/public_html -name .htaccess -print
```

---

For example, if you ran the first mentioned command at:

```
/home/your_account/public_html
```

It will give `.htaccess` files from that folder and any other folders above `chmod 444`, so:

```
/home/your_account/public_html
/home/your_account/public_html/other_dir
/home/your_account/public_html/other_dir2
/home/your_account/public_html/other_dir/other_inner_dir
```

and so on.

Comment: If I want to add this command to cron, can I specify the path manually?

Comment: @MarkKorzhov in addition I suggest you to run the print command I posted to make sure it gives you the desired result before setting it to update or run any commands to the files. `find . -name .htaccess -print`

Comment: I strongly advise anyone reading this against "chmod 444 .htaccess"'ing this file. What it did for me, was not allow me to write to the entire web root anymore. This is not the proper chmod for .htaccess, we want it completely inaccessible from the world (clients) but accessible from the webserver.

Comment: @JerryCattell Make sure you read the whole answer **It will give .htaccess files from that folder and any other folders above chmod 444**, if you need those folder with a different permission you can always change it